# ModalPopUpExtender with Animations Tag

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a problem that I am creating a ModelPopUpExtender Control in my web page. It is running fine without Animations Tag but when I added a Animations Tag within it, it returns an error as "**Animation on TargetControlID="Button2" uses property AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender.OnShowing that does not exist or cannot be set**"

I don't know why it returns this type of error? Please suggest me any solution regarding the same.

Thanks in advance.

**Code:**

```
 <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="Button2" CancelControlID="Button4" PopupDragHandleControlID="Panel2" DropShadow="true">
         <Animations>
                <OnShowing>
                <FadeIn Duration=".5" Fps="30" />
            </OnShowing>
            <OnShown>
                <FadeIn Duration=".5" Fps="30" />
            </OnShown>
            <%-- neither animation works from code-behind --%>
            <OnHiding>
                <FadeOut Duration=".5" Fps="30" />
            </OnHiding>
            <OnHidden>
                <FadeOut Duration=".5" Fps="30" />
            </OnHidden>

            </Animations>
        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Animations>
 <OnShown><Fadein Duration="0.50" /></OnShown>
        <OnHiding><Fadeout Duration="0.75" /></OnHiding>
</Animations>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="ModalPopupExtender2" TargetControlID="Button2"
                            PopupControlID="Panel2"
                            DropShadow="true"
                            BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
                             CancelControlID="Button4">

<Animations>
 <OnShown><Fadein Duration="0.50" /></OnShown>
 <OnHiding><Fadeout Duration=".05" /></OnHiding>
 </Animations>
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="PnlDesignation"  ScrollBars="Auto" CssClass="loginpnl" style="display:none">

     <div class="closepop text-right" id="Button4" > </div>

</asp:Panel>
```

CSS

```
.modalBackground
{
background-color: #000;
filter: alpha(opacity=70);
opacity: 0.70;
}

.closepop  
{
margin:0 0 0 20px;
BACKGROUND: url(../images/close.png) no-repeat 0 0;
 WIDTH:26px;POSITION: relative; background-position:right;
HEIGHT: 26px; 
cursor:pointer;
z-index: 100000;
 float:right;
}
```